# Usage of rpy2 with a custom installation of R

Tags: python, linux, r, rpy2

Dear fellow programmers,
I would like to use R inside of a ipython notebook. On the system (Centos) I am working on exists an older version of R (2.15). I was able to execute R-code with this version in a ipython notebook, however, I need a newer version of R with extra packages and because I don't have administrative right for that machine, I have a local machine on which I installed the newest version of R (3.1.2). I compiled the source on my pc and flagged it in a way that it can be assessed by extensions. After that I installed rpy2 with pip and this installation went without any errors.
I also can import the rpy2 package, but when I try to load libraries, I get an error message:

```
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/my/homedir/Software/R-3.1.2/library/stats/libs/stats.so':
  libRlapack.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
During startup - Warning message:
package \u2018stats\u2019 in options("defaultPackages") was not found
```

I looked it up, all libraries are present and I don't get an error when I use R without ipython.
Anyone has ideas?

Best,
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#rpy2
It's very weird when you say you need admin right to update R version because R usually doesn't require admin right to be installed. Make sure you install that under your user folder, instead of somewhere in the system drive.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, these are all windows binaries, but as I wrote, we use Centos. Regarding the installation of R, maybe I didn't make myself clear, but there is a centrally administered version of R which I can't change, so I installed a custom version under my own folder.